# Folding all functions in a R-Studio Script

Tags: r, rstudio, folding

Basically I've written quite an amount of functions in one R-Script. To create a  better overview and that i don't have to scroll too much, i usually press the arrow on the left side of a function definition, which folds it. 
This can be quite annoying to do for over 30 functions as they continiously "unfold" when i run them.
What i mean  with the folding can be seen in this picture

[image]

Does someone know a keyboard shortcut for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct solution to the folding problem, but an easier way to navigating massive scripts is with the drop-down list in the bottom of the source editor. It lists all defined functions in the active window.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In Rstudio, you can click on `Edit -> Folding -> Collapse All`

[image]

The keyboard shortcut to that is `Command + Option + O` on mac.

Comment: This would sadly collapse other parts that I have marked with ### or ---, as well. I'm looking for a solution to only collapse the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seem not possible.

I think the best is to learn some rules to apply systematically:
[RStudio folding rules](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections)

**A section that one can fold using the "Edit -> Folding -> Collapse All" will be any comment line (starting with #) which includes at least four trailing dashes (-), equal signs (=), or pound signs (#)**

Instead of collapsing the { }, one could insert the section as expected by R, then use the "Edit -> Folding -> Collapse All".

Note: this will not work nicely with a selected region and "Edit -> Folding -> Collapse".

From the following code:

```
# function1 ####
function1 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
# function2 ====
function2 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
# function3 ----
function3 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
# function4 ####
function4 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
#### function5 ####
function5 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
```

I can fold it this way:

[image: Folded code Rstudio]

If one always use the same way to define function, it is possible to use awk to actually add a section before each function definition:

```
awk '{ if( $0 ~/function/ ) { print "####" $0 "\n" $0 }else{ print $0} }' code_function.R
```

From the following code contained in the file **code_function.R**

```
function1 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
function2 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
```

I run in a (linux) terminal:

```
awk '{ if( $0 ~/function/ ) { print "####" $0 "\n" $0 }else{ print $0} }' code_function.R > code_function_withSections.R
```

and I obtain the following file -- ugly file -- but a fast way to modify a 10000-functions file.

```
####function1 <- function(x){
function1 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
####function2 <- function(x){
function2 <- function(x){
    somecode <- 0
    test <- 3
    mean(c(1,2,3))
}
```