# Create Shortcut For Code Folding Curly Brackets

Tags: r, macros, rstudio, code-organization

I use the curly brackets `{}` to help organize my R-code. The collapse/expand all macro does not work on curly brackets. I am aware that I could make addins and assign them to a shortcut / keybinding. Is there a way for me to create a shortcut (i.e. using addins) that will collapse/expand all `{}` sections of my code?

##### Example:

Prior to pressing shortcut:

```r
x = 4

# Adds 2
{
    x = x + 2
}
```

After pressing shorcut:

```r
x = 4

# Adds 2
{ ... }
```

Comment: This isn't about R, it's about some editor that you're using.  Is it RStudio?

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370298/folding-all-functions-in-a-r-studio-script Using `Command + Option + O` in Rstudio

Comment: @user2554330: Yes, RStudio.

Comment: @Ronak Shah: unfortunately no. That works for functions, which is great; however, I use curly braces without a function for general organization 'cause I can collapse and copy-paste. And when an error occurs, it doesn't keep running - this is a feature I really like when using the curly braces. In Rstudio, the example code I have (above), is not affected by the "collapse all" option, though it is affected by the "expand all" option.

Comment: An option in RStudio is to use a comment followed by 5 dashes, e.g. `# section_name -----`, can be collapsed with Cmd+Alt+L and expanded with Cmd+Shift+Alt+L. This has some benefits over braces (1) Sections are named, with names visible when collapsed, + optionally in an outline shown on right side (2) They're comments, so are guaranteed to have 0 effect on the code (3) Even if you could collapse between braces, you'd need extra logic to tell which set are the section-identifying ones, vs. e.g. function-definition. The ----- is easy to detect and implement folding for in e.g. vim

Comment: @IceCreamToucan: that sounds like an okay backup option if there is not a way to achieve my specific goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/latest/rstudio_ide_commands/rstudio_ide_commands.html

##### Example:

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "fold")
```

This lets you fold the currently selected section of code. Using other basic commands from rstudioapi, I can easily build an addin that does what I want.